# I can’t get google maps installed in my ionic 2 application

Tags: cordova, google-maps, angular, google-maps-api-3, ionic2

I followed the document [here](http://ionicframework.com/docs/v2/native/google-maps/) to install the native google maps SDK

I executed this

```
"$ ionic plugin add cordova-plugin-googlemaps --variable API_KEY_FOR_ANDROID="YOUR_ANDROID_API_KEY_IS_HERE" --variable API_KEY_FOR_IOS="YOUR_IOS_API_KEY_IS_HERE"
```

on google dashboard no API_KEY for each platform , it's only one API_KEY for all

anyway , it always gives me this error

[image]

Comment: Might be an obvious question. Have you tried moving the project to a different path?

Comment: No , is it will work

Comment: It seems to be taking the path as a command for whatever reason (maybe  related to paranthesis?). I am not certain though

Comment: so , what to do ?

Comment: try moving to a different path..maybe 1 folder above

Comment: Not working , because it's not IONIC project folder :))

Comment: I meant copy your project to different folder .

Comment: the error goes out , it says google maps plugin already installed
,, -- also when trying the application on the browser it says google maps plugin is not installed 'D

Comment: cordova plugins work only on device or emulator..also add plugin with `--save` option

Comment: still the same issue , the plugin not installed
-- also not works on my device  , this code http://pastebin.com/vumX3pMa , should open the map - right ?

Comment: check these errors : http://i.imgur.com/Tcx2yqF.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/135505/discussion-between-ahmed-mohsen-and-suraj).

Comment: am not in a position to chat..sry

Comment: which is your ionic version in package.json?

Comment: Nevermind , "ionic-angular": "2.0.0-rc.4"

Comment: you need to call plugin methods inside platform.ready().then

Comment: it's in ionic 1 , I'm using ionic 2 :))

Comment: yeah..its the same in ionic 2..check the docs